# Include .env file in `go build` command

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I have the following **Dockerfile** which builds an image for my Go project.

```
FROM golang:1.11.2-alpine3.8 as go-compile

RUN apk update && apk add git
RUN mkdir /app
COPY src/ /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN go get github.com/joho/godotenv

RUN go build -o main .

FROM alpine:latest

RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=go-compile /app/main /app/main

CMD ["/app/main"]
```

The image builds, but my ".env" file is not included in the Docker image.

I've tried to copy the ".env" from the `src` folder into the image using `COPY src/.env /app/.env`, but still the Go code can't find/read the file.

How can I include the ".env" file, or in fact any other non Go file?

Answer (score 5):

You cannot include non-go files in the `go build` process. The Go tool doesn't support "embedding" arbitrary files into the final executable.

You should use `go build` to build your executable then, any non-go files, e.g. templates, images, config files, need to be made available to that executable. That is; the executable needs to know where the non-go files are on the filesystem of the host machine on which the go program is running, and then open and read them as needed. So forget about embeding `.env` into `main`, instead copy `.env` together with `main` to the same location from which you want to run `main`.

Then the issue with your dockerfile is the fact that the target host only copies the final executable file from go-compile (`COPY --from=go-compile /app/main /app/main`), it doesn't copy any other files that are present in the go-compile image and therefore your `main` app cannot access `.env` since they are not on the same host.

---

As pointed out in the comments by @mh-cbon, there do exist 3rd-party solutions for embedding non-go files into the go binary, one of which is [`gobuffalo/packr`](https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr).

Comment: i think it should be said that solutions to embed files to a go bin exists, see for example https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr

Comment: Also also, in the absence of a `WORKDIR`, the final Dockerfile stage will run out of the container's root directory; if the program is looking for `$PWD/.env` or `$HOME/.env` it's worth checking that those line up.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject a dotenv file or single variables into your service using docker compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  backend:
    ...
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    env_file:
      - ./backend/.env
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two build phases. Copy the .env file from your first build phase into where the main file is. It should look like this:

```
 COPY --from=go-compile /app/main /app/main
 COPY --from=go-compile /app/.env /app/.env
```